# I'm trying to use AJV to validate a file but it always says valid even when I try to make it error

Tags: node.js, json, jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to use AJV to validate a file but it always says valid even when I try to make it error.

It there something that needs to be set to get it to report errors?
Any pointers would be helpful.

Code sample - My schema and JSON file is too large and complex to place here.

```
*#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var file3 = 'JsonSchema3.json'

var schema = fs.readFileSync(file3);
var data = fs.readFileSync('XXX-0000000-01-err.json');

var ajv = new Ajv({schemaId: 'auto', allErrors: true, verbose: true});
ajv.addMetaSchema(require('ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-04.json'));

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
if(validate) {
       console.log('schema compiled');       
} else {
       console.log('did not compile');
}
var valid = validate(data);
if (valid) {
  console.log('User data is valid');
} else {
  console.log('User data is INVALID!');
  console.log(validate.errors);
}*
```

Thanks

Mike

Comment: If you can't share your schema, there's nothing we can do for you. You're going to have to prune your schema to something you can share.

Comment: "My schema and JSON file is too large and complex to place here." - This suggests there is likely something wrong with your schema. You need to create a Minimal Reproduceable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - You may find it helpful to use https://jsonschema.dev if it's a single schema file.